# How can I delete a generic static class instance in C#? I.e. public static class Observer<T>, Destroy(Observer<string>);?

Tags: c#

I have a generic class, lets call it "Observer".

```
public static class Observer<T>
{
    public static Action<T> Trigger = (x) => { };
}
```

So anytime I want to use this, I might call:

```
    Observer<Player>.Trigger += OnPlayerChange;
    Observer<Player>.Trigger(p);
```

The problem is that I have no way to remove the generic instance of Observer for "Player".  So its memory remains.  I can clear the values, but their defaults will still exist.

Is there a way to actually remove the reference?

Comment: Does `Observer<Player>.Trigger -= OnPlayerChange;` not work?

Comment: If you need to control its lifetime, why is it a static instance in the first place?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - No.  That would remove the Trigger, but the Type Observer<Player> would still exist.  Any static memory its taking will still exist.

Comment: Is this causing an observable problem? Does the class have a lot of static data, or you're creating thousands of them via reflection or something?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It could be an instance method, but it adds more work.  A considerable amount of what I'm looking for is to take an existing code base that is heavily dependant on singletons, and make it more testable.  There are multiple ways I could approach it, and I'm exploring my options.

Comment: @Blorgbeard No, its not a memory issue.  It is a state issue.  During the lifetime of the application, it is not an issue.  But for testing it certainly is.  During the testing, I need to guaranty particular states, but in static code, it becomes difficult.  If there was a way that I could kill/reset all static structures, without having to reset the code, it would be easy.

Comment: Ah yes, static code and testing don't mix so well.. I don't know the details, but I'd consider refactoring away from static state. You could make `Observer<T>` into a (per `T`) singleton, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observer<Player>` is a type, not an object instance.  As soon as you reference that type, the static constructor and initializers will execute and the type will be loaded into the AppDomain.  The only way, as far as I know, to unload a type, is to unload the entire AppDomain.  That said, I don't think a loaded type by itself holds onto a lot of memory, and managing AppDomains is pretty cumbersome, and almost certainly not worth the effort just to unload a type.   Usually they are used for managing entire assemblies that need to be dynamically loaded or unloaded, or for completely isolating executing code within the same process.  But if you really need to unload a type, that option does exist.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/ for more details, if you really want to go that route

I would recommend, however, that you figure out why loading a type is causing a problem and how to manage it another way.  For example, if your real problem is that Observer has a static member that keeps some large amount of data referenced and pinned, you could release it manually:

```
public static class Observer<T>
{
    public static Action<T> Trigger = (x) => {
        referenceToALotOfMemory = new byte[100000];
    };
    private static byte[] referenceToALotOfMemory;
    public static void IAmDoneWithThisType() {
        referenceToALotOfMemroy = null;
    }
}
Observer<Player>.Trigger += OnPlayerChange;
Observer<Player>.Trigger(p);
Observer<Player>.Trigger -= OnPlayerChange;
Observer<Player>.IAmDoneWithThisType();
```

This of course is fraught with many concurrency problems if you do any kind of multi-threading, and has a pretty bad "code smell".  It would be a whole lot easier, safer, and more readable to simply convert to a non-static instance:

```
public class Observer<T>
{
    public Action<T> Trigger = (x) => {
       referenceToALotOfMemory = new byte[100000];
    };
    private byte[] referenceToALotOfMemory
}

var observer = new Observer<Player>();
observer += OnPlayerChange;
observer.Trigger(p);
observer -= OnPlayerChange;
//let the garbage collector cleanup referenceToALotOfMemory when the time is right
```